# Change background image with querySelector every 10 sec not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, setinterval

I try to change the background image in the div every 10 seconds to a random image (img/1-10.jpg).

The background changes only once and not every 10 seconds as it should change
... I am getting ALERT every 10 seconds (so setInterval does work).

```js
function update() {    
  window.setInterval(function() {
    alert('ok');
    document.querySelector("#ri-grid div:nth-child(1)")
      .style
      .backgroundImage = "url(img/<?php echo rand(1,10);?>.jpg)";
  }, 10000); 
}

update();
```

```css
.grid--layout-1 .grid__item:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url(img/1.jpg);  
  transition: background 5s linear; 
}
```

```html
<div class="grid grid--layout-1 grid--current" id="ri-grid">
  <div class="grid__item 0"></div>
  <div class="grid__item 1"></div>
  <div class="grid__item 2"></div>
  <div class="grid__item 3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: must be something to do with the way you are setting the image. try using `Math.random()` in javascript instead of using `<?php echo rand(1,10);?>` with the img name

Comment: That's because PHP's `echo` is called only **once** per page load. Use respective JS means instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate random number by using JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function update() {    
        window.setInterval(function() {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1; // Generates random number from 1 to 10
        document.querySelector("#ri-grid div:nth-child(1)").style.backgroundImage = "url(img/" + index + ".jpg)";
        }, 10000); 
        }

        update();  
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. If I have an ARRAY of images whose name is different from the other (like img/a.jpg img/abc.jpg img/pp.jpg) What can I do?

Comment: var images = ["a", "bb", "pp"];
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
var image = images[index];

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
```

instead of PHP code:

```
<?php echo rand(1,10);?>
```